# Document for CSS differences between IE and FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

Is there a layman document out there describing what are the differences in rendering CSS styles between IE and FF (or IE and the rest of the world) that is more straightforward than quirksmode.org, which is very specification-centric? for example, I just wasted a lot of time figuring out one difference in rendering tables with different width styles between table rows and the table itself, which I couldn't find quickly in the quirksmode table...

Comment: Make this question CW and wait a few days, maybe this question could become that document... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a decent (and non-headache-inducing) list of some issues with Internet Explorer, mostly IE 6.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

Someone might be able to do me one better though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a reference list... but the one issue which comes to mind for me (and it's not quite CSS) is the placement of your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

IE will not pay any attention to your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration if it is not the very, very, very first thing on the first line of the file. If you put your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration anywhere else IE starts to do whatever it wants with the rendering of your document.

I've seen even the most seasoned professionals bugger this up; they think "Oh, hey, I'm using a DOCTYPE; everything must be good now, right?" WRONG.